# Can I expect to see monk seals in Zakynthos, Greece?

Tags: nature-and-wildlife, greece, islands

They seem to be living there and the island is not big. However I have also read, that the colonies are secret. Is it probable to randomly see a seal there? Or are there even guided tours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no specific monk seal tours, and this is great since the monk seals are highly endangered. However, you may randomly see a seal when on a sea turtle tour.